# Wave antiparticle duality

Tags: wavefunction, antimatter, wave-particle-duality

Can an antiparticle such as the antiparticle of an electron - a positron exhibit wave particle duality? We know from de Broglie, and the Davisson-Germer experiment in which we fire electrons from an electron gun, towards a double slit(carefully arranged), there is an interference pattern observed. Fire single electrons too, at a time towards the double slit and over time an interference pattern emerges.

Is this true for the antiparticles too? For instance, if we fired positrons, towards a double slit, will an interference pattern emerge- though what apparatus might capture such an antimatter interference pattern is another point of discussion(whether single positrons are fired at a time, or more). Will there be an interference pattern observed for positrons too?

Answer (score 2):

Antiparticles have the same duality, but you have to take their annihilation with your equipment's ordinary matter into account before you do your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The wave particle duality applues to EVERYTHING. Larger particles have higher frequencies and so scatter more/behave more like a particle.. with the same mass a positron will behave the same way as an electron.